How to make agents stay at certain patch in NetLogo?
The agents in my model are the countries and I want to make each one of them on a different patch to be far away from each other and make them stable as they do not move.
I couldn't try anything as I'm still learning and I don't know anything about codes
This is my code so far :
turtles-own [
  military-strength
  economic-strength
]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 20 [
    set size 1 + random-float 6
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor  ; Set initial location to a random patch
    set shape "flag"
    set color one-of [blue green red yellow orange pink cyan magenta brown black gray violet]
    set military-strength random-float 0.2 + 0.1
    set economic-strength [1 2 3]
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go 
  ask turtles [fd 0]
end 


It's not clear at all what you are trying to achieve. Try explaining in plain english what your goal is.

If you want the turtles to move to a patch a certain distance away then you can try this.
turtles-own [
  military-strength
  economic-strength
]

globals [
  r
]

to setup
  clear-all
  set r 10; change this value
  
  create-turtles 20 [
    let valid-position? false
    while [not valid-position?] [
      setxy random-xcor random-ycor
      if all? other turtles [
        distance myself > r
      ] [
        set valid-position? true
      ]
    ]
    
    set size 1 + random-float 6
    set shape "flag"
    set color one-of [blue green red yellow orange pink cyan magenta brown black gray violet]
    set military-strength random-float 0.2 + 0.1
    set economic-strength one-of [1 2 3]
  ]
  reset-ticks
end




Q: "How to make agents ... stay at certain patch in NetLogo?"

Using your initial idea, sketched above, we may proceed to a structure, where to set and control what parts of the indicated solution. The high level definition was something like "Rule 1 : move, if too close. + Rule 2 : stay, if not so."

This template helps you decide details, that were not defined in full details above, yet helps to extend the working solution further on :
breed [ allStates aState ] ;; -------- Here we define our [ agents agent ] breed

allStates-own [ ;; ------------------- Here we define our agents' attribute param-s
  powers-of-ai
  powers-of-oil
  powers-of-gas
  powers-of-gold
  powers-of-debt
  powers-of-money
  powers-of-economy
  powers-of-military
  powers-of-propaganda
  powers-of-past-failures
  powers-of-current-instabilites
  powers-of-leading-by-own-good-examples
  powers-of-principal-weaknesses
  powers-of-exported-culture
  powers-of-influence
  powers-of-ethics
  powers-of-faith
  powers-of-will
  powers-of-love
]

to find-a-direction-and-move ;; ------ Here we compute agent's best ( policy given ) direction
   ;;  heading towards ...
   set heading a-least-bad-direction
   ;;  the jump <distance> will have to be also policy-specific,
   ;;                       the more to warrant at least some meta-"stability" in
   ;;                       the Sim-WORLD scene
   jump how-far-to-move
   ;; ------------------- FINALLY ----
   ;; NOP
end

to-report a-least-bad-direction ;; --- Here we specify a policy of least bad move
   ;; returns a heading... with...           a least-bad policy-specific property
   let least-bad random-float 360
   ;; ------------------- FINALLY report <aValue>
   report least-bad
end

to-report how-far-to-move ;; --------- Here we specify a policy of least bad move or stay inplace
   ;; returns a distance in ... direction of a least-bad policy-specific property
   ifelse any? allStates in-radius 5 [
      let how-far random-float 1
      ;; ---------------- FINALLY report <aValue> ;; in JIT/RET-mode
      report how-far
   ][
      let how-far 0
      ;; ---------------- FINALLY report <aValue> ;; in JIT/RET-mode
      report how-far
   ]
   ;; ------------------- FINALLY report <aValue> ;; in JIT/RET-mode never gets here
   report -1
end

to setup ;; -------------------------- Here we initialize The Sim-WORLD
   ;; ------------------------- CLEARs
   clear-all
   reset-ticks
   ;; ------------------------- WORLD
   resize-world -180 180 -90 90
   set-patch-size 2
   ;; ------------------------- AGENTs
   create-allStates 10 [
      ;; set each of our agent's initial attributes' values
      set shape "butterfly"
      set powers-of-leading-by-own-good-examples 0.0
      set size 5
   ]
   ;; ------------------- FINALLY ----
   ;; NOP
end

to go ;; ----------------------------- Here we call all actions of evolution for Sim-WORLD
   ;;
   ask allStates [
      find-a-direction-and-move
   ]
   ;; ------------------- FINALLY ----
   tick ;; -------------- FINALLY tick
end

